# Nonzero stress on crystal at equilibrium volume?

Tags: condensed-matter, pressure, solid-state-physics, crystals, density-functional-theory

Using a first principles computational method such as DFT, you can calculate the energy of a unit cell at different volumes to obtain a parabolic energy vs. volume curve.

The minimum of this curve denotes the equilibrium lattice constant for a crystal.

Following the same procedure with calculating pressure vs. volume, however, yields more of a cubic polynomial shape which intersects the volume axis at a particular volume close to the equilibrium lattice constant.

QUESTION:
The volume at which there is zero pressure is not exactly the volume that has minimum energy (i.e., the "lattice constant" has nonzero pressure). How can this be the case? I would imagine the system strives to be in a state of zero energy AND pressure, unless I did my DFT calculations incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DFT calculations, pressure is computed as the energy derivative with respect to volume:
$$ P=-\frac{dE}{dV} $$
So the pressure should indeed be zero where the energy is a minimum.

If you look through [this slideshow](http://media.quantum-espresso.org/santa_barbara_2009_07/slides-exercices/Tutorial_stress.pdf) you'll see the user encounters a similar problem to you. The issue in their case is inadequate convergence. So you may want to increase the number of plane waves you're using and try a stricter convergence criterion.